# s3 object storage bucket list operation implementation mechanism, how to ensure performance

Tags: amazon-s3, ceph

How can the file list of s3 buckets be stored to ensure the performance of the list and fast data recovery.How does the usual Internet solve this problem, and what are the general solutions.Is distributed KV storage usually used?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? this is a discussion not a question

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak for ceph as S3 back end, you'll want your bucket index pool on fast drives, here's an excerpt from the [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_ceph_storage/4/html/object_gateway_for_production_guide/assembly-developing-storage-strategies-rgw-prod):

> Index: At least one CRUSH hierarchy SHOULD be for the index pool,
> where the CRUSH hierarchy maps to high performance media such as SSD
> or NVMe drives. Bucket indices can be a performance bottleneck. It is
> strongly recommended to use SSD or NVMe drives in this CRUSH
> hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am also a ceph developer and know the pain points of ceph rgw's index pool

Comment: If the number of buckets is large, the list operation will block other requests, and slow recovery is a fatal problem